# Blazor: Passing complex types as parameters

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to componentize my simple application, and it all worked while everything was in one single component. However when I move the button logic into it's own child component and out of the main component, I get the following

```
Unable to set property 'story' on object of type 'Shared.ChoiceButton'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid
```

I can see that's its a casting error, however when I try the same thing with primatives, it works. What trick am I missing to get this to work with complex types?

**Parent Component**

```html
<div id="choices">
    @foreach (var choice in story?.currentChoices)
    {
        <ChoiceButton story="@story" choice="@choice" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    public Story story;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        story = new Story(await Http.GetStringAsync("sample-data/Deamons.json"));
    }
}
```

**My new child component (ChoiceButton)**

```html
<button class="choiceButton" @onclick="() => Choose(choice)">@choice.text</button>

@code {

    [Parameter] public Story story { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Choice choice { get; set; }

    void Choose(Choice choice)
    {
        story.ChooseChoiceIndex(choice.index);
        story.ContinueMaximally();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the new Story(await... what happens when you remove the http call from that contructor?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but your parameters in ChoiceButton are Capitalised, but when you use ChoiceButton and pass values, you used lower case. C# is case sensitive, so will not recognise "story" as a parameter on ChoiceButton.

Comment: @MisterMagoo The parameters in choice button are lowercased and match what gets passed in, the Types are uppercase. `story` is of type `Story` and `choice` is of type `Choice`

Comment: You're right I was not reading carefully!

Comment: @Flores I tried moving the await into its own variable above, console write line the result to make sure it's there and then pass it into Story() and I get the same issue.

Comment: Is it possible to post the whole project somewhere? Hard to tell without the whole context.

Comment: If you can't post your entire project, at least try to post the full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: Is `story` by any chance a value type (struct)? In that case I'd have a lead.